dropdown menu disappearing?
I have a wordpress website, dennisroliff.com. I have a problem with the main menu. In particular the dropdown menu under 'galleries'. I'm finding that if I move my cursor down the dropdown menu too quickly, it disappears. This would be very frustrating for a potential client.
<nav id="navigation" class="clearfix"> <div class="menu"><ul id="menu"
> class="clearfix be-nav-link-effect-2"><li id="menu-item-4905"
> class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom
> current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-4905"><a
> title="home" href="https://dennisroliff.com/"
> aria-current="page">home</a></li>   <li id="menu-item-21"
> class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page
> menu-item-21"><a title="about"
> href="https://dennisroliff.com/about/">about</a></li>   <li
> id="menu-item-107" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom
> menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-107"><a
> title="galleries" href="#">galleries</a>   <span
> class="mobile-sub-menu-controller"><i
> class="icon-icon_plus"></i></span><ul class="sub-menu clearfix">   <li
> id="menu-item-7175" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type
> menu-item-object-page menu-item-7175"><a title="INTERIOR IMAGES"
> href="https://dennisroliff.com/interior-images/">INTERIOR
> IMAGES</a></li>   <li id="menu-item-5690" class="menu-item
> menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-5690"><a
> title="FASHION IMAGES"
> href="https://dennisroliff.com/fashion/">FASHION IMAGES</a></li>   <li
> id="menu-item-10928" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type
> menu-item-object-page menu-item-10928"><a title="FOOD IMAGES"
> href="https://dennisroliff.com/food-samples/">FOOD IMAGES</a></li>  
> <li id="menu-item-12665" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type
> menu-item-object-page menu-item-12665"><a title="FAMILY PORTRAITS"
> href="https://dennisroliff.com/family-portraits/">FAMILY
> PORTRAITS</a></li>   <li id="menu-item-10698" class="menu-item
> menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-10698"><a
> title="VIDEOS" href="https://dennisroliff.com/videos/">VIDEOS</a></li>
> <li id="menu-item-9500" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type
> menu-item-object-page menu-item-9500"><a title="COMMERCIAL"
> href="https://dennisroliff.com/commercial/">COMMERCIAL</a></li>   <li
> id="menu-item-3290" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type
> menu-item-object-page menu-item-3290"><a title="FLASHES OF HOPE"
> href="https://dennisroliff.com/flashes-of-hope/">FLASHES OF
> HOPE</a></li>   <li id="menu-item-108" class="menu-item
> menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-108"><a
> title="CW PROPERTIES INC."
> href="https://dennisroliff.com/commonwealth-properties-inc/">CW
> PROPERTIES INC.</a></li>   <li id="menu-item-4884" class="menu-item
> menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-4884"><a
> title="NEW DIGITAL WORKFLOW"
> href="https://dennisroliff.com/new-digital-workflow-a-work-in-progress/">NEW
> DIGITAL WORKFLOW</a></li>   <li id="menu-item-10054" class="menu-item
> menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children
> menu-item-10054"><a title="PRODUCTION" href="#">PRODUCTION</a>   <span
> class="mobile-sub-menu-controller"><i
> class="icon-icon_plus"></i></span><ul class="sub-menu clearfix">   <li
> id="menu-item-6801" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type
> menu-item-object-page menu-item-6801"><a title="MODEL SHOOT"
> href="https://dennisroliff.com/taylor-piatt-composite-production/">MODEL
> SHOOT</a></li>   <li id="menu-item-6680" class="menu-item
> menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-6680"><a
> title="AKRON CIVIC PROJECT"
> href="https://dennisroliff.com/production-first-energy/">AKRON CIVIC
> PROJECT</a></li>   </ul>   </li>   </ul>   </li>

I just want the dropdown menu to stay viewable until someone clicks on one of the categories.

I've taken all the fluff out of your question. Please take a moment to edit that single line of code into a readable code block.
